# How to add published scoped in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Having a hard time manipulating Azure AD B2C scopes. What kind of permissions do we need to be able to do this?

**Mine**

[image]

**The one I found on the net the person is editing it.**

[image]

Comment: Is this link which you found?:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-b2c-access-tokens-now-in-public-preview/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and I found this issue caused by that I **didn't add my APP ID URI** . Then I add it and I could add Published scopes.

The point you should pay attention is as following image:

[image]

The result:This issue had been resolved.

[image]

Comment: Wayne Great answer. Just marked this as an answer. This was our original problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237776/azure-active-directory-b2c-token-issue

Comment: My UWP needs an Api Scope.  How do I use this if I have a 'Native Client'?

Comment: This answer still applied today