# Scope Issue with Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I started to study a little bit Azure AD B2C and I was following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/) tutorial.
I'm able to login/logout and I can correctly see the list of the "logged" users in the "Users and Groups" blade (on the azure portal). So I'm thinking that everything is working well. In the "***msal.service.ts***" I'm using the following configuration:

```
tenantConfig = {
  tenant: "brianennotest.onmicrosoft.com",
  clientID: '7c94b737-786c-4e1c-9231-0a0d803ac47c',
  signUpSignInPolicy: "B2C_1_SiUpIn",
  b2cScopes: [""] };
```

As you can see I left an empty array in the b2cScopes.
There I've the error:

> AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid profile' provided in request must specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.

I thought I can't leave it blank so I used:

```
b2cScopes: ["https://brianennotest.onmicrosoft.com/TestB2C/user_impersonation"]
```

but I received another error that says:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Can I have some help? I already tried to read the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237776/azure-ad-b2c-token-issue) but didn't help.
Thanks

Comment: The b2cScopes vaule should be `b2cScopes: ["<your App ID URI>/<SCOPE>"]`. Try to add a custom scope in Azure B2C portal and add the scope again.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not related to b2c but to Angular itself, you need to add a

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

tag in your app component file